# Adding a personal repo to fork of another repo on Git

Tags: git, github

I am working on a collaborative project that I created my own personal repo for. I realized that I should have been working out of the fork. I decided to fork and clone the projects down and just drop my project in the fork. My role was just to add additional files not related to the original repo. When I push up this version of the updated fork, the repo that I added is grayed out. I imagine this is because there is no pointer to the source. Is there anyway around this? Can I remove all git references with my personal repo code so that I don't get this problem?

Comment: Check out a clean version of the forked project, copy over your additional files to the clean fork and create a new commit.

Comment: my additional files are my personal repo, so when I push up changes my files i.e. repo is grayed out. I want to remove git references, so its as if I am just adding files and not a repo from somewhere else. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Have you made any commits on master (the question is did you keep your commits on specific branches so they could be merged by pull requests in the future) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new clone of your personal repo. In there, delete the .git folder (this will delete all history etc for this clone).

Next, copy over (on the local filesystem) the .git folder from your local clone of the fork into the local clone of the personal repo.

Now, git will think that your repo is the fork, with the changes you made applied but not yet commited. You can create a new commit and push that new commit to the fork.